# Disconnect socket.io and send the disconnect reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, socket.io

I need to disconnect some users from server using this code:

```
socket.disconnect('User disconnected because of ....');
```

but when i handle the disconnect event on user side i don't see the disconnect reason

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(reason){
console.log('User 1 disconnected because '+reason);
});
```

I am using node for server side and browsers as client side, Any idea how to send a disconnect reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem there is no way to do such a thing like that but you can do the trick using emit function before closing the socket

Code in server side:

```
socket.emit('closeReason','User disconnected because of ....');
socket.disconnect();
```

Code in client side:

```
socket.on('closeReason',function(reason){ ... });
```